# Función no se ejecuta al pulsar botón

Tags: javascript, html, css

quiero hacer que al pulsar un botón, el display de un div cambie de row a column, y viceversa, he estado probando pero no entiendo porque este código no funciona. En la consola se imprimen los dos número, pero no cambia el display, he probado a poner column sin las comillas y tampoco funciona.

```
function change() {
    console.log('1');
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'column';
    console.log('2');
}
```

Comment: display column no existe, querrás decir flex-direction column talvez?

Comment: `table-column` también existe

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Franco y Emeeus, el display no recibe ningún parámetro llamado column, recibe: none, block, inline, etc.

podrías intentar usando el flex-direction así:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.flexDirection = "column";
```

No estoy segura si eso es lo que buscas...

Answer (score 0):

yo creo que te referis al flex-direction, en caso tal, seria asi:

```
document.getElementById('container').style.flexDirection = 'row';
```